# How addDisposeCallback() in knockout js is working

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

first see a small custom binding code.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dialog = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || {};
        var dialog;
        alert($(element).attr('id'));
        //do in a setTimeout, so the applyBindings doesn't bind twice from element being copied and moved to bottom
        setTimeout(function() {
            var dlgOptions = { 
                autoOpen: true, 
                close: function(event, ui){
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            };            
            $.extend(dlgOptions, options);

            dialog = $(element).clone().dialog(dlgOptions);
        }, 0);

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).dialog("destroy");
            dialog.remove();
        });
    }
};
```

code was taken from this url http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/8Cfqz/39/

what are the below line about ?

```
ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
    $(element).dialog("destroy");
    dialog.remove();
});
```

what is `domNodeDisposal and addDisposeCallback` ?

when addDisposeCallback() is called ?

what is the relation between **addDisposeCallback() and checkbox** uncheck event ?
if there is any relation then tell me how it is established?

what this line is doing `$.extend(dlgOptions, options);`

what this line is doing `dialog = $(element).clone().dialog(dlgOptions);`

Comment: `domNodeDisposal` and `addDisposeCallback` are both explained in the knockout documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-disposal.html

Comment: yes i understand but do not understand why this function `addDisposeCallback` will be called when user uncheck the check box ? how relation is establish in code not clear. any one can help me to understand. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`domNodeDisposal` and `addDisposeCallback` are both explained in the knockout documentation: knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-disposal.html

They allow you to hook into the knockout disposal handlers to add your own cleanup code. In the example you have, it's to destroy the jQueryUI dialog.

The template used to show the dialog is wrapped with a `ko if` virtual element that is tied to the observable bound to the checkbox. When the observable is true, the template is rendered. When false, it is removed. By calling `addDisposeCallback`, you are adding your own extra cleanup code to be executed when knockout removes the element (dialog), which will clean up the dialog element before it is removed (getting rid of event handlers).

Comment: can u plzz come up with few sample code which explain the usage of addDisposeCallback() very easily.

Comment: the sample code you're using is a good example, as is the code on the page I linked you.